# GitHub Issue:Commiting/pushing duplicated Java Spring root folder to a different repository

Tags: git, github

i am new to git and i have this issue and couldn't find any answer so far.

I have a Java Spring project on my D drive in a Projects folder.I Copied + pasted the app root folder on the desktop(duplicated the same app) and opened the project from this new location.
The project has git enabled, so after copying it , the copy folder project commits to the same repository as the original one.

I have tried setting a new repository to commit to with `git remote set-url origin <repoURL>` but it seems it just sets this new repo for both of my projects, the original one on the D drive and the copy on the desktop.So both start commiting to the new repo.

My question is how can i set a different repository for the copied project so that the original project keeps its old repository ?I want each project to commit and push to a different repository even if the projects are the same.

**L.E.** I found the issue.Even if i had 2 different projects in 2 different locations my terminal was pointing at the same place so i had 2 tabs of intellij opened with 2 terminals but executing the set command in the same folder each time.

Comment: This has nothing to do with java nor with Spring. What do you mean with `The project has git enabled`? Does the copied folder have a `.git` (mayby hidden) folder?

Comment: Yes the original folder on the D drive has a .git folder.When i copied the whole project folder to desktop , i copied it with this .git folder aswell.So now both projects(original and copy) comit/push to the same repository on github.I want the copy folder to commit and push to a different repository without changing the repository for the original folder wich happens when i use ```git remote set-url origin <repoURL>```

Comment: You can try to add another remote origin to the copied folder `git remote add <somename> https://github.com/user/repo.git`. Make sure that you really copied the project folder and not just made a soft link somehow.

Comment: ok so you say i should use git remote add origin <my project git url> with the new repository for the duplicated project on the desktop and then use git remote set-url origin <my project git url> for that same project?And this will change only my duplicated project repository ? right now when i use git remote -vv in both projects (original and duplicated one) i have the same repository.

Answer (score 0):

Create a fresh new repository in GitHub but do not initialize it. Now make a copy of your project and delete the .git folder inside the copied project folder. This will remove all tracking information. Now initialize this as a new repository with following commands.

```
git init
git remote add origin <url_to_new_repo>
git add .
git commit -m "First commit to new repo"
git push origin master
```

Comment: does not work, as soon as i deleted the git folder and use git init inside IDE terminal i get an error ```fatal: remote origin already exists.```